# Why didn't the example here use "too"?

Tags: word-usage

I was reading about [excess](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/excess)  and in one of the examples I found this,

> They both eat to excess.

Why didn't this use 'too' instead of 'to'? It does not make sense to me, I don't know why.

Comment: **To excess** is a rather highbrow way of saying **too much**.

Comment: Because this is **to** in the (metaphorical) sense of "direction towards".  **too** means "also", which doesn't make sense here.

Comment: *They both eat [up] [**to** the point of becoming](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+the+point+of+becoming%22) obese*.

Answer (score 1):

"To" is correct because "excess" is a noun.

Here, "to" is a preposition that indicates the extent. This is from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to):

> **to** *preposition*
> **d (2)** —used as a function word to indicate the limit of extent
> *// stripped to the waist*

In your example sentence, it means they ate so much that it was excessive.

"Too" is incorrect because it can only modify *gradable* words, like certain adjectives and adverbs. "Too" is sometimes used before a noun, but it means the noun is being used as an adjective or adverb:

> This painting is beautiful, but **too Warhol** for my living room.

In this example, "Warhol" is understood to mean "Warhol-like" or "similar to Warhol's art".